# Show Inline reply in Android Custom Notification View

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create a custom notification layout with an inline reply option. But the reply action is not shown in the notification. Though, the same works fine with the default notification view.

```
 android.app.Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.app.Notification.Builder(context, Constants.CHANNEL_ONE_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(getBitmap(userId, getAvatarText(userId)))
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent);



        RemoteViews collapsedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_collapsed_notification);

     String replyLabel = "Reply";
        android.app.RemoteInput remoteInput = new android.app.RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();

        android.app.Notification.Action action = new android.app.Notification.Action.Builder
                (Icon.createWithResource(WorkspaceApp.getInstance(), android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat), "Reply", pendingIntent)
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build();
notificationBuilder.setCustomContentView(collapsedView);
notificationBuilder.addAction(action);
 NotificationManager notificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    //notificationBuilder.addAction(action);
                    notificationManager.notify(notifId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

R.layout.view_collapsed_notification used for collapsed view. Which contains title, content and image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                tools:text="Raksha User" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                tools:text="Raksha User" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/smiley_thumb" /> </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your R.layout.view_collapsed_notification xml?

Comment: Added layout file. Please check and help me in resolving this issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi RKS, I tested your code with a few changes and it is working. I think you should use support library with NotificationCompat.Builder. I added a few things like creating a channel for notifications and a pending intent. It is working good.

Comment: this is the link to my code that i used. https://gist.github.com/abdullahlogicon/d5163aaaee3100e93a9c8d3fd7b4e6cd